# Fire a macro on formula result change across two workbooks

Tags: vba, excel

My problem is quite simple : I have two workbooks (let's say they are wb1 and wb2).

On ws2 of wb2, I have on `Range("A1")` a formula like `='[wb1.xlsm]ws1'B1` . So,  when B1 on ws1 of wb1 changes, A1 on ws2 of wb2 changes too (that's the goal).

**My problem is** how to fire a macro when the value of A1 on ws2 changes ? `Worksheet_Change` doesn't fire, and `Workbook_SheetChange` isn't fitting in this case...

**EDIT** By the way, `Worksheet_Calculate` doesn't fit too. Indeed, I don't know where the value on ws2 will change.

Comment: If the only way for cell A1 on ws2 in wb2 to change is if someone changes cell B1 of ws1 in wb1, then put a `Worksheet_Change` event on ws1 in wb1, watching for when its cell B1 is changed.

Comment: Yep. The problem is that I don't know exactly the name of wb2 (but wb2 know the name of wb1). So, if in a macro, wb1 is calling for wb2 but wb2 changed it's name, an error will appear.

Comment: How many workbooks do you have open beside wb1 and wb2?  If the answer is none, then wb2 is whichever workbook does not have a `Name` of `wb1.Name`.

Comment: And the answer is not none. To be clear, wb1 is something like a database of the turnover of a company, and wb2 to wbi (i can be something like 10) are the workbooks of the turnover of each employees.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Before answering your question I feel compelled to highlight that there are lots of [really good reasons](http://www.wizardofexcel.com/2015/03/22/linking-spreadsheets-dont-do-it/) to avoid linked workbooks.  It always ends in pain, misery, lost data and long wasted hours spent trying to track data back to its source.  Rant over, here is how you can ignore my advice.

This code uses the [VBA collection](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yb7y698k(v=vs.90).aspx) object, which is pretty rubbish.  VBScript includes the much better [dictionary object](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee176993.aspx), which you can use within VBA.  I would highly recommend investigating this further...

There are two parts to the code.  The first element is run once.  It finds and begins tracking every external reference in a given sheet.

```
' Find all formulas that point to external workbook.
' Store current value.
Sub Initialise()
    Dim c As Range      ' Used to loop over all cells, looking for external.

    ' Ready collection for use.
    Set ExternalFormula = New Collection

    For Each c In [Sheet1].UsedRange

        ' Check if external, will start: =[
        If c.HasFormula And c.Formula Like "=[[]*" Then

            ' Value added to collection contains key, for later use.
            ' Collections cannot return keys.
            ' Dictionaries are better, but require an external reference.
            ExternalFormula.Add c.address & "~~~" & c.Value, c.address
        End If
    Next
End Sub
```

The next section is included in the `Calculate` event.  `Calculate` doesn't provide the updated cell address.  But using the `ExternalFormula` collection we can figure out which cell has been updated.

```
' Check external formula for changes.
Private Sub Worksheet_Calculate()
    Dim c As Integer            ' Used to loop over forumla.
    Dim address As String      ' A1 style address of current forumla.
    Dim oldValue As String      ' Value before any updates.

    ' Loop over stored values, looking for change.
    If ExternalFormula.Count > 0 Then
        For c = 1 To ExternalFormula.Count

            ' Extract address and old value.
            address = Split(ExternalFormula.Item(c), "~~~")(0)
            oldValue = Split(ExternalFormula.Item(c), "~~~")(1)

            ' Check for changes.
            If [Sheet1].Range(address).Value <> oldValue Then

                ' Change found.
                MsgBox address & " updated", vbInformation

                ' Update stored value.
                ExternalFormula.Remove address
                ExternalFormula.Add address & "~~~" & [Sheet1].Range(address).Value, address
            End If
        Next
    End If
End Sub
```

Using the dictionary object would dramatically reduce the number of lines of code in that function.

Don't forget to declare `ExternalFormula` at the workbook or worksheet level.

```
Private ExternalFormula As Collection       ' Stores all external forumulas.
```

Comment: Hey, that's so cool ! But is it fast ? Looks like, but I don't know if it is really. I'll try this later.  For your first advice, I know but I can't change it. It's not my job to do that, and I really don't like how they built their Excel files. If only one Excel file change it's name, everything is broken. I don't know why they did that. Anyway, thanks a lot, i'll try this. Clément

Comment: Speed could be an issue.  It depends on the number of external formulas and the size of the used range (which is every cell from A1 to the furthest row and column that has held a value).

Comment: Around 8 columns by 500 rows. :(

Comment: That should fine.  We're only talking 4,000 cells (8*500), which won't take the VBA long to crunch.  Just tested on 20,000.  Took less than a second.

Comment: Hey. It works, thanks a lot. Just modified the Like formula. You helped me a lot, thanks. Clément.